# How can I bridge this gap between the wall (painted brick) and roof inside my 1890s house?

Tags: walls, crack, gap

There is a gap between the roof and the brick wall in our kitchen. It doesn’t seem to leak. How would you fill it?

[image: Photo of gap between roof and wall]

Comment: I think I can see brick edges for scale. Is that opening about 1.5" to 2" at its widest? Is there attic access from above? My first instinct would be to cut a sliver of wood and attach it from the attic side to narrow the gap sufficiently for quarter round trim and caulk.

Comment: That's surely the ceiling and not the roof?

Answer (score 1):

The classic answer would be to put up some kind of molding.

Crown molding is large enough to hide many sins, and looks lovely, but is complicated to install well.

But it doesn't have to be that fancy. My 1880's house uses that solution in most of the older rooms. Living room has simple 1" cove molding stained dark, entryway has a fancier profile painted to match the ceiling.

In many cases, hiding an imperfect junction is exactly what molding is for.

Comment: To state the obvious, don't just put molding/trim up to cover this gap, run it around all 4 walls...

Comment: There's a significant kink in the photo's wall surface. Crown molding large enough to cover the opening would be too stiff to work with such a kinky wall.

Comment: I did say crown was hard. Thin stuff can often be bent to close most of the gap, then a bit of putty/spackle can close the rest if desired. Remember that almost nobody climbs up on chairs to stare at ceiling lines --heck, most barely notice the ceiling exists unless there some obvious and major feature or flaw.